# Clang, С++, отделение интерфейса от реализации, ошибка компиляции

Tags: c++, clang

Os X El Captain, Clang 7.0.2 (XCode Comandline Tools)

Есть простой класс `BP2`, в которм есть только конструктор, принимающий `int` и переменная `int`.
Класс разделен на интерфейс *BP2.h* и реализацию *BP2.cpp*. Программа запускается из *main.cpp*.
При команде `clang++` *main.cpp* выводиться следующее:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86-64:
>   "BP2::BP2(int)", referenced from:
>   _main in main-716a27.o
>   ld: symbols not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

<s>Код не привожу, ибо написал его как пример для изучения проблемы. Он очень прост.</s> Порядок включения файлов таков:

- в *main.cpp* `#include "BP2.h"`
- в *BP2.cpp* `#include "BP2.h"`

Код из комментариев:

```
// BP2.h 
class BP2 { public: BP2(int); private: int justInt; }; 

//BP2.cpp 
#include "BP2.h"
BP2::BP2(int intJust) { justInt = intJust; } 

//main.cpp 
#include "BP2.h"
int main() { BP2 myBp(0); return 0; }
```

Компилирую командой 'clang++ main.cpp'
я так понимаю Clang просто не видит BP2.cpp. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Ответ не привожу, ибо он очевиден. На самом деле, подумайте, к чему это ведет: `в BP2.cpp #include "BP2.cpp"`

Comment: Извините, ошибся. Конечно же в BP2.cpp #include "BP2.h" ><

Comment: Вот поэтому и надо приводить код, если хочется получить ответ, а не догадки.

Comment: На Стэк задал вопрос впервые и то с телефона, без возможности раздать интернет на ноутбук. Если вкратце.

Comment: И, эм, последняя версия Clang 3.7, с версиями определённо что-то не так.

Comment: BP2. h "class BP2 { public: BP2(int); private: int justInt; }; //BP2.cpp #include "BP2.h" BP2::BP2(int intJust) {justInt = intJust;} //main.cpp include "BP2.h" int main { BP2 myBp(0); return 0; }

Comment: По поаоду версии: по clang -v пишет этот номер. Я так понимаю, что эта версия соответствует 3,7.

Comment: clang не может не видеть файл, если ему его передали. Где строка, как Вы компилируете файлы? Кстати, код надо вставлять в вопрос — не надо его помещать в комментарии, его невозможно читать в них.

Comment: Предполагаю, что Вы компилируете командой вроде `cxx main.cpp`. Надо при компиляции задавать все файлы: `cxx main.cpp BP2.cpp`.

Comment: @Konstantin Спасибо! Вопрос решен.

Comment: @KonstantinLes Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если проект состоит из нескольких файлов, то все эти файлы должны участвовать в сборке.

В данном конкретном случае возникает ошибка при компоновке: по объявлению класса в `BP2.h` компилятор генерирует вызов к конструктору, предполагая, что  его определение производится в другом месте; т.к. файл `BP2.cpp` не участвует в сборке, то компоновщик не обнаруживает требуемого конструктора и выводит сообщение об ошибке.

Самый простой путь решения проблемы - указывать все файлы исходного кода при сборке:

```
cxx main.cpp BP2.cpp
```

Для простых проектов такой способ подойдет. Однако для более сложных проектов лучше освоить какую-нибудь систему сборки, например, `make`.